# Issue with race condition betwen 2 Controllers in Angular.js with Ajax and a localStorage value

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, promise, race-condition

The value for myIdentity is created only once and is persistant saved in the local storage after first usage of the following Angular.js controller.

The function $scope.createIdentity() is a complex function in a more global controller and saves the result to $localstorage.myIdentity. 
This perfectly works!!! the createIdentity() function works with Q promise inside for itself.
But in the AppCtrl I have an issue with race conditions because $localstorage.myIdentity is not yet resolved before 
my $http XHR Request is fired. So it doesn’t contain any value for myId.

This occurs only the first time the controller is used.

But I need to start the socket.io connection at the first call of the AppCtrl and this is here an bigger problem for me.

At a second usage of AppCtrl the correct value for myIdentity is yet available in $localStorage.

```
TimeacleControllers.controller('StatusCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'Socket', '$localStorage',
function ($scope, $http, Socket, $localStorage) {


    if ($localStorage.myIdentity === undefined) {
        $scope.createIdentity();
    }

    var myParams = {
        myId:  $localStorage.myIdentity
    };

    $http
        .post('http://example.org', myParams)
        .success(function (data) {
            console.log('received data: ' + data);

            Socket.connect();
            Socket.on('connected', function () {
                console.log("Connection!");
            });

            Socket.on('message', function (msg) {
                console.log("Message: " + msg);
            });

        })

        .error(function (err) {

            // Handle login errors here
            console.log("Error - " + err);
        });

}]);
```

So what can you do here to make the Ajax Request wait until the $localstorage.myIdentity can be resolved? Please help.

Comment: If you have these constraints then perhaps you should refactor.  Use a service for createIdentity and something like getid.  You can use a promise to kickoff your socket calls which you can even resolve in the router before the route is changed if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned about Q promise but having problem with async sequence...?

If `createIdentity` is returning a promise, just put the http call inside `.then`

```
$scope.createIdentity().then(function() {
    $http.... // or you can wrap it inside a function
})
```

---

**Edit:** If you have no access to the code that populate the variable (normally happens inside directive), you can setup a one time watch to monitor the value change.

```
var unwatch = $scope.$watch(function(){
  return $localStorage.myIdentity;
}, function(newValue){
  if (newValue === undefined) return;

  $http...

  unwatch();
});
```

Comment: Of course normally this wouldn't be a problem here, but this is different. The createIdentity() should only run once the $localstorage.myIdentity is not set. In this programflow I have actually no idea how to make the Request wait until $localstorage.myIdentity is saved. I didn't say, that the createIdentity() is returning a promise. It works for itself with different promises and if they are all resolved, it saves the Identity in localStorage.

Comment: @lcycool:  I have no Idea what you mean. Can you maybe give an example fitting the code I submitted? I can't see where you wait for the $scope.createIdentity()  to save the value.

Comment: This part is to put in the place of your $http call. It watches change on `$localStorage.myIdentity` until it has a value, then proceed to call $http

Comment: Thx, I will try this tonight. then I post the experience ;-)

Comment: Perfect solution for my issue. damned. Good Idea and Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You said `$scope.createIdentity()` uses a promise (and presumably is an async operation). Make it return a promise for your code to observe. When it resolves, make it resolve the identity.

Promises are chainable. When you return a promise from `then`, the next `then` listens for that promise instead of the original promise. In this case, we make the next `then` listen to the AJAX.

```
$scope.createIdentity().then(function(identity){
  // When createIdentity resolves, use the data for the AJAX.
  // Return the AJAX promise for the next chained then.
  return $http.get(...);
}).then(function(data){
  // When the AJAX completes, use the data for the socket call
  Socket.connect();
  ...
});
```

Comment: This is clear, but it doesn't fullfills my needs. Let me try to go deeper. I don't want to resolve the createIdentity() promise again if the $localstorage.myIdentity is available.  I reduced the code of the ajax success. I can not always start a connect there. So it is complicated. I just want to wait with the complete http block until the $localstorage value is available.

Comment: @gwinger You can store the promise of `createIdentity` in some variable. Attaching a `then` to an already resolved promise will execute the handler immediately.

Comment: can you give an example? I have to read in the $localStorage value. This is only that way possible to do the ajax in my circumstances. If it is not yet set, I can not do the Ajax. I have to wait only then. The identity function is a very complex function with high performance costs. So this would be the bad way.